# Boostrap summernote inside the CSS class well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

When I put a [summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) inside the CSS bootstrap class `wells`, the background color of summernote turns into grey as expected. But how do I keep the background color of summernote its default which is white.

```
<div class="well well-sm">
     <div class="form-group">
          <div id="summernote"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is straight CSS not working?

```
#summernote{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Worst case, you could slap an `!important` on the background-color rule.

Comment: No strangely this doesn't work even with `!important`

Comment: And to add, removing the `well` css and setting the `background-color` as you suggested above does not change its background color. So I am not sure what sets the color of summernote's text editing area

Comment: On inspecting summernote's editable text area it seems the `note-editable` is the CSS class that needs to be altered. That has solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

summernote has a .note-editable class which you could target like so:

```
.note-editable {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```